# Apply button in CDialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a dialog in which after pressing button OK, the program uses the data in the dialog and draws a plot. I need to draw the plot without having to close the dialog as with IDOK, hence the apply button.
The code with drawing the dialog is,

```
INT_PTR val = dlg->DoModal();
if (    val == IDOK) {
  //draw plot
}
```

The code of onOK and onApply

```
void DLg::OnOK() {

    GetDataGrid();
    CDialog::OnOK();
}

void DLg::OnBnClickedApply()
{
    GetDataGrid();
}
```

How do I get DoModal() to return a value on onApply() without closing the dialog?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to put drawing into a separate thread and would call it wherever needed. So you can either

(1)  call the OnDrawPlot again in your Apply button

```
if (    val == IDOK) {
   AfxBeginThread(...);//draw plot
}
void DLg::OnBnClickedApply()
{
   AfxBeginThread(...);//draw plot
}
```

(2) send the return value back to the DoModal using EndDialog method

[What parameters are there in EndDialog ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472(v=vs.85).aspx)
An example can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111809/can-i-return-a-custom-value-from-a-dialog-boxs-domodal-function)

Answer (score 3):

A modal dialog can't return a value and leave the dialog open. You could either make your dialog non-modal, or post your main window a message from the `OnBnClickedApply` function that makes it draw the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable in `CDialog` derived class preferably `public`. Then just at `OnOK` assign this variable to appropriate value. The caller would use it directly.

```
class Dlg : public CDialog
{
public:
   int TheVariable;
...
};
```

Call site:

```
if(dlg.DoModal()==IDOK)
{
    dlg.TheVariable; // Use the variable
}
```

However, if you need to draw on the dialog itself (and not to other window, which has launched the dialog), then **don't** call `CDialog::OnOK` or `EndDialog` in your `OnOK` override. In this case, you need to do painting in dialog itself.