# How do I close a MFC Modal Dialog in another thread and can get the dialog return value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a MFC dialog project. There is a download button in the main dialog, click it would prompt a progress bar and start download. When the download finished, I want to it closed automatically.

```
void CProgressBarTest::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    static auto funDownload = [&]() {
        m_downloadRetValue = ::SomeDownloadAPI(funDownloadCallback);

        //When download finished, close the current dialog (progress bar). Here are two options:
        //EndDialog(IDYES); // causes crash
        //::PostMessage(this->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);// doesn't crash, but without return valud IDYES.
    };

    m_thDownload = std::thread(funDownload);
}
```

Here are two methods to close the progress bar:

`EndDialog(IDYES)`: it causes crash.

`::PostMessage(this->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)`: it can close the window without crash, but there also no return value (IDYES).

I want to do such check on the outside,

```
void CGUIThreadTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    CProgressBarTest dlg(this);
    INT_PTR nRet = dlg.DoModal();
    switch (nRet)
    {
    case -1:
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Dialog box could not be created!"));
        break;
    case IDYES:
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Yes!"));
        break;
    case IDOK:
        // Do something 
        break;
    case IDCANCEL:
        AfxMessageBox(_T("IDCANCEL!"));
        break;
    default:
        // Do something 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both dialogs you create this way belong to the main (UI) thread. `EndDialog()` must be called from within the "dialog procedure", and this runs in the main thread too. So the problem seems to be that you call `EndDialog()` from the download thread. An easy workaround (and imo technically correct) could be to post a custom message (eg `WM_APP + nn`) from the download thread to the dialog window, when the download completes or fails. In response to this message you can call `EndDialog()` with the desired return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post an [application-defined message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-app) from the download thread to your main GUI thread like this:

```
BOOL CProgressBarTest::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    auto funDownload = []( HWND hwnd ){
        auto const downloadRetValue = ::SomeDownloadAPI(funDownloadCallback);

        ::PostMessage( hwnd, WM_APP_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED, static_cast<WPARAM>( downloadRetValue ), 0 );
    };

    m_thDownload = std::thread(funDownload, GetSafeHwnd());

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Note 1:** I'm using `OnInitDialog()` to launch the thread because `DoDataExchange()` is a really bad choice as it will be called multiple times. `OnInitDialog()` will be called exactly once.

**Note 2:** A captureless lambda is used to better decouple the download thread from the GUI thread. Passing `this` from a GUI dialog to a worker thread is a recipe for disaster as it makes it so tempting to just write to GUI thread variables, ignoring required synchronization. Apart from that, less coupling comes with less dependencies which is always a good thing.

What is `WM_APP_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED`? This is my [application-defined message ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-app) which I usually define like this:

```
enum {
    WM_APP_0 = WM_APP,
    WM_APP_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED
    // for future extension...
};
```

Add a message map entry:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProgressBarTest, CDialog)
    ON_MESSAGE( WM_APP_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED, &CProgressBarTest::OnDownloadFinished )
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And define the message handler to return a value from the dialog that depends on the download result:

```
LRESULT CProgressBarTest::OnDownloadFinished( WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp ) 
{    
    m_thDownload.join();

    auto const downloadRetValue = wp;
    EndDialog( downloadRetValue == ERROR_SUCCESS ? IDYES : IDCANCEL );

    return 0; 
}
```

Make sure to `join()` the thread as I did above to avoid a crash in the `std::thread` destructor, which requires that the thread has been joined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a workaround.

[Can I return a custom value from a dialog box's DoModal function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111809/can-i-return-a-custom-value-from-a-dialog-boxs-domodal-function)

Don't use the DoModal's return value. Just add a member function for `CProgressBarTest`.